# Angularjs Jasmine mock method called on controller instantiation

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a simple component like this:

```
.component('myComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'example.html',
    controller: function() {
        function serviceCall() {}

        serviceCall();
    }
});
```

What I want to do is spy on the serviceCall method to return some predefined json. The issue is that to get the controller, I need to do something like

```
var myComponent = angular.element('<my-component><my-component>');
myComponent.element.controller('myComponent');
```

But I can't call that until the component is created, and I can't create the component because I didn't yet mock the method call.

How do I get around this catch-22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's pretty much no way around it unfortunately.

However, assuming that your `serviceCall()` function internally calls a function in a service, you can spy that. (Remember Angular good practice - separation of concerns principle)

Assumption of your code:

```
.component('myComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'example.html',
    controller: function(SomeService) {
        function serviceCall() {
            SomeService.someFunction();
        }

        serviceCall();
    }
});
```

You can inject the service in your test and spy the function expected to be called as such:

```
var SomeService;

beforeEach(inject(function (_SomeService_) {
    SomeService = _SomeService_;
}));

it('should call someFunction', function () {
    spyOn(SomeService, 'someFunction').and.returnValue({
        then: function () { // Mimic a promise
            return ... mocked object ... ;
        }
    });

    // Instantiate the controller

    expect(SomeService.someFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();

    // Expect stuff to have happened in the controller with the returned value

});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Brilliant. Let me try that out

Comment: Yup, looks great!